# Should I do a redirect when trailing slash and http is changed?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, redirects, 301-redirect

I have noticed that all my internal links (and I have a lot of them) were being linked like so:

```
https://websitenamehere[dot]com/post-title
```

Yet, my posts have actually a trailing slash after the title, like so:  `https://websitenamehere[dot]com/post-title`

When I check Google Search Console, I can see like 26.5k links being excluded, because they don't have this trailing slash *("Page with redirect: The URL is a redirect, and therefore was not added to the index.")*. But when I check out the URL of the one with the trailing slash, they are all indexed and seem fine.

My question: does it still make sense to redirect them or shouldn't I care, as the proper/canonical ones are already indexed?

And would this have an effect on SEO in the first place?

**PS:** I recently went from `http` to `https`, but I can see that almost all https are properly indexed. Should I care to redirect still?

Answer (score 1):

Google is just telling you that it doesn't add redirects to its index. This is fine and normal. Continue to redirect to the trailing slash version, which is the version that Google will index.

Comment: So you are saying that I should indeed do redirects (via htaccess) from http:// to https:// and from /post-name to /post-name/ (with slash at end)?

Comment: Yes indeed. Redirect each page to its canonical URL.

Comment: Also try and update any links you have that still out to http or do not have the trailing slash.

Comment: Thank you. I will make sure I'll do that. Doesn't this mean, though, that I will have some dip because I am using redirects?

Comment: No dip, since if I understand correctly, your canonical urls are already indexed.